# One-way One to Many relationship using part of a composite key

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, foreign-keys, relationship, one-to-many

I have a model in EF similar to this

```
Person
    PK Guid Id
    PK DateTime DateSynced

Test
    PK Guid Id
    FK Guid PersonId
```

In Entity Framework 6.2, I really only care about Navigation Property on Person with reference to a collection of Tests.  I do not need a property of Test.Persons or anything like that.

I really just want to have Person.Tests where Test.PersonId = Id regardless of DateSynced.  There will eventually be many persons with the same Id, each with a different DateSynced DateTime.

Is this doable or do I need a Many-To-Many with an intermediate table?

I understand that EFCore has a concept of Alternate Keys and I thought I might could leverage that in this effort, but there does not seem to be a corresponding functionality in EF 6.2

## Edit

I have the following Fluent rule in my OnModelCreating override.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Test>()
    .HasRequired(t => t.Person)
    .WithMany(p => p.Tests)
    .HasForeignKey(t => t.PersonId);
```

I get the following exception complaining about the Dependent and Principal role constraints:

`The number of properties in the Dependent and Principal Roles in a relationship constraint must be identical.`

As I understand it, this is because I am referencing an entity with a 2-part composite key by only one part of that key.  What I am looking for is a way to do exactly that.

Comment: That's pretty standard stuff. What exactly are you having trouble with? What's not working? Maybe share some code from what you've tried.

Comment: @Ben I have updated my answer with additional context.  What I am looking to do is establish a relationship to a composite keyed entity with only part of that key.

Comment: Oh, `DateSynced` is part of your primary key. That's...an unusual way to go about it. I'm not sure what the "right" way to handle this is, but I would just not define the relationship and instead manually handle the join you're after in my code (i.e., just write LINQ that joins on `PersonId`..

Comment: An SQL FK constraint (which is not actually a relationship but a fact about the DB) says some column's subrow values appear elsewhere where they are PK/UNIQUE. In the referenced table they must be declared PK/UNIQUE. It doesn't matter what the columns have to do with constraints in the referencing table. (We say the FK is from the referencing table & columns to the referenced. If the referenced columns are not PK/UNIQUE then you don't have a case of a FK & SQL can't declaratively constrain.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Paraphrase or quote from other text. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Make your post self-contained.

Comment: Noted and fixed.

Answer (score 2):

The foreign key on the second table must match the PK on the first.

For example, using Int for the key type for simplicity.

If I have a Person with a PK of ID: 1, SyncDate: 2019-05-22

Then I add a second variant: PK of ID: 1, SyncDate: 2019-05-23

If I go to add a "Test" record, which Person record would it reference with a FK Person ID of 1? It would reference both records, hence EF cannot support a reference of "HasRequired" pointing to a single Person record.

To reference one variant of Person ID 1, your Test record will need both a PersonId and a SyncDate to identify the record:

```
public class Test
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid PersonId { get; set; }
    public DateTime SyncDate { get; set; }

    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}

modelBuilder.Entity<Test>()
    .HasRequired(t => t.Person)
    .WithMany(p => p.Tests)
    .HasForeignKey(t => new { t.PersonId, t.SyncDate });
```

Tables in the database cannot reference each other based on a partial FK unless a many to 1. I.e.

```
Person
------
PK: PersonID

PersonComment
-----------
PK: PersonId
PK: CommentDate
```

In this example a Person can have many PersonComments based on the PersonID link, while a Comment can resolve back to the Person via the Person ID. As a FK.

In a table structure that has:

```
Person
------
PK: PersonID
PK: Version

PersonComment
-------------
PK: PersonCommentID
PersonId
```

PersonId in the PersonComment cannot be a FK to Person because it doesn't reflect the PK to the Person table. You can legally have this table structure, but PersonId is just a dumb, unconstrained column. You can query all Person records manually using it, but you will get all Versions of the person. There are no constraints etc. to ensure that the Person ID on a comment matches an Id on the Person table.

If you don't care about the versions of a Person You can have a Test entity with a Person ID, but EF can't associate that to Person entities, you'll have to load Person records manually from the Context.

When it comes to the purpose behind your schema structure, I would suggest looking at possible alternatives. For instance, if your goal is to track versioned data I would suggest looking at something like:

```
Person
PK: PersonId
** Person Fields

PersonHistory
PK: PersonHistoryId
FK: PersonId
VersionDate
** Person Fields

Test
PK: TestId
FK: PersonId (if applies to current person, or PersonHistoryId if a specific version)
```

Then "Person" reflects the person in it's current state, containing a collection reflecting the History. From there you can prevent modifying the Person fields via private setters and DDD-style methods which would be responsible for composing a new History record based on the current Person data before updating the Person values. This way a Person record can be historical and preserve it's ID for related entities.

Comment: Thanks.  I figured it was not doable (these are not my requirements) but wanted to see if there was any possibility.  I think that what I will go with is a View on the Person table of the "Most Current" persons.  These will be single PK unique, and thus will be much easier to relate to the tests in a One-To-Many.  I just wish there was an easier way to inform the powers that be that their requirements suck.

Comment: @CodeWarrior Don't blame business rulers for the pitiful deficiencies of (SQL &) SQL DBMSs. Standard SQL actually supports arbitrary declarative DB constraints expressible via queries. No reasonable business can express its constraints only via PK, UNIQUE, NOT NULL, CHECK, FK & indexes. Trigger-implemented constraints are a necessity for sound practical SQL DBMS software engineering.